# How to hide Admin Menu (backend) in Joomla 3?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, admin, controlpanel

How to hide 'System > Control Panel', 'Components', 'Help' these 3 menu items in joomla3? Sorry not enough reputation to post image. =.= Certain user groups do not need to access/view these. I have hide the rest such as 'Users', 'Menus', 'Contents', 'Extensions' but can't hide these.

Comment: As this question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

Removing  help item could easily done from:

```
Extensions -> Module Manager -> Administrator -> Admin Menu -> Advanced -> Help Menu: Hide
```

For the rest of the menu items you have to make an override to the admin menu module.

You have to download:

```
/administrator/modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default_enabled.php
```

And copy to:

```
/administrator/templates/*your_admin_template/html/mod_menu/default_enabled.php
```

You have to check if active user is not to the level that you don't want to show the menu item (id: 18) in our example. So for control panel item you have to change:

```
$menu->addChild(new JMenuNode(JText::_('MOD_MENU_CONTROL_PANEL'), 'index.php', 'class:cpanel'));
```

To:

```
if(!in_array(18, $user->groups)){
$menu->addChild(new JMenuNode(JText::_('MOD_MENU_CONTROL_PANEL'), 'index.php', 'class:cpanel'));
}
```

And for components menu you have to find:

```
if ($components)
```

And change to:

```
if ($components && !in_array(18, $user->groups))
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Is there any way to change it without change the php?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is the only solution but uses template override so you won't have problem updating your joomla installation.

Comment: @mmm: take a look at this out-of-box solution http://foobla.com/joomla-goodies/admin-menu-hider, no code touch.

Answer (score 1):

Log into your back-end using a username that has Super Administrator privileges

Set to new user - Publisher group (or any other except Administrator/Supper Administrator )
Edit access rights in System -> Global Configuration -> Permissions
Set:
Site Login
Allowed
Admin Login
Allowed
Offline Access
Denied
Super User
Denied
Access Administration Interface
Denied
...

help menu:
Go to the Module Manager
Choose Administrator from the dropdown (Site/Administrator)
Choose the module "Admin Menu" and Edit
In Advanced menu choose "Help Menu" value -> Hide

Comment: Hi! How about to hide 'System'? There are 'Control Panel', 'Clear Cache', 'Purge Expired Cache' in 'System'.

Btw, able to hide the Help menu! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in override creation:

1. goto Template Manager
2. Click on Templates
3. Click on Template name.  In my case "Isis"
4. Click on Create Overrides
5. Click on "mod_menu"

Now those files will be available via FTP here: public_html/administrator/templates/isis/html/mod_menu

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `administrator/modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default_enabled.php` from whichever template you are using for administrative area (for instance, mine is IsIs).

Find the following block of code

```
/*
 * Help Submenu
 */
if ($showhelp == 1)
{
```

And change the if condition (`$showhelp == 1`) to `$showhelp == 0` and the help menu disappears.